# Mysqli_Num_Rows Error, "expects parameter"

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm creating a few lines to check if a user exist within the database. To do this, I was going to just find the username in the DB and if there IS a user with that name in the database use num_rows to make it show that their is a user with that name.

The error is:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, 
boolean given in /home/bluef/public_html/SMNS/register.php on line 36
```

Code:

```
$usernamef = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Users 
                                 WHERE Username =".$Username."");

$usernamefound = mysqli_num_rows($usernamef);

if($usernamefound != 0){
    echo "Username in use, try another username?";
}
```

Comment: Please check out the "Related questions"-section on the right...

Comment: Strings need to be quoted in SQL statements; but if you're using mysqli, why aren't you using prepared statements and bind variables?

Answer (score 1):

- **Always** have this line before `mysqli_connect`

  ```
  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
  ```
- **Always** format your queries correctly.
- **Always** use prepared statements when you need to insert a variable into query.
- **Always** check out the "Related questions" section on the page (Or suggested questions while writing your own).

Answer (score -1):

Try this with your query

```
$usernamef = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Users 
                                 WHERE Username =".$Username."") or die(mysqli_error());
```

to see the error. Also you can try this

```
 $usernamef = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS myCount FROM Users 
                                     WHERE Username =".$Username."") or die(mysqli_error());

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($usernamef)
if( $row['myCount '] > 0 )
{
  echo "Username in use, try another username?";
}
```

Check this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp

Also you can try with mysql_query and mysql_num_rows() and not with mysqli_query()